# Looking for a reference that explains the use of vba classes

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and now I am trying to start using classes because I see that otherwise my programs are too hard to work with and I always writing the similar pieces of code over and over.

Can you recommend any book that covers user-defined objects in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) well? Because everything that I found just gives a short introduction on this subject.

While I was searching for such a book, I found a lot of advanced books on [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net). As I understood this language is more "powerful" (can be used for wider variety of tasks).

Comment: Good intro reference http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx

Comment: The first thing that I have read)) Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could look into books on VB6. The majority of content for VB6 applies to VBA with little or no modification. Here's a chapter of an online book about classes: http://www.visualbasicbooks.com/progVB6samplepg1.html From browsing through it, it seems pretty basic (just like classes in VBA).

Comment: In addition to looking at the vba links everyone less has posted I would strongly recommend you search for and look over general language independent object-oriented programming introductions to get good ideas on how to use classes.  Cheek out [this link](http://www.lynda.com/Programming-tutorials/Foundations-of-Programming-Object-Oriented-Design/96949-2.html). These wikipedia pages on OOP may be helpful too, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Comment: I've got an ancient and battered copy of this old O'Reilly book http://www.amazon.com/VBA-Nutshell-Languages-Paul-Lomax/dp/1565923588 which is pretty useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to learn about VBA, look for references on **VB6**. You can probably find lots of references and books for cheap. I consider myself very good at VBA, and this is how I learned a lot. Even the newest version of VBA (VBA7) is esentially a subset of VB6. Most of what you can learn about VB6 is completely applicable to VBA, particularly in regards to classes and UDTs (which are kind of like `structs` in the .NET world).

- Start at the source -- MSDN: [Visual Basic 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127540.aspx)
- When you search,  use VB6 rather than VBA if you're not finding what you need, for example:

  - [Google: "vb6 class inheritance"](http://www.google.com/search?q=vb6+class+inheritance) --> http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2970

From my own experience I would say that user-defined types (declared using the `Type` keyword) are rarely useful *except for* private use within in a single module for the purpose of native function declarations which require a pointer to a certain structure. Their fundamental drawback is that they cannot be cast to and from `Variant`, which is a killer for advanced VBA. Once you get used to it it's not too hard to quickly build a class (a class module in com VB lingo) with the same fields.

*Post script:* This will not help you when learning about classes or user defined types, so I add this merely as a post script: You can also find lots of good information by searching for **VBScript**. Most VBScript can be pasted directly in to a VBA project and it will run, with small exceptions like not having access to the  `Wscript` object. Many of the documentation examples such as for [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for interacting with both XML files and the internet) show VBScript, and all of this code can be readily used in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA Developer's Handbook by Getz and Gilbert gets my vote. It's old and out of print, but you can get an electronic copy here https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Ken_Getz_Vba_Developer_s_Handbook?id=46toCUvklIQC&feature=null-Mike+Gilbert

It's a bit of a beast, but a great book

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET is a full programming language - which does not need to run "in" Excel.
There are several ways to "connect" VB.net and Excel, e.g. "Com Interop" or integrating the code into a workbook (I am vague here because I have never done the latter one myself).
The ease of use is difficult to acess - if you only want to work with internal Excel data, VBA is better suited, simply because it is faster. If you want to read data from the internet, store / load data or build your own UI vb.net is waay faster because VBA can do all this things, but it is like using a screwdriver to pound a nail into the wall.

Comment: How does this address VBA classes?

Comment: He asked about VBA, which does have classes and can be used. I use them a lot. I greatly prefer C# or VB.NET -- but not when I _have_ to work in MS Access or Excel. VBA has full access to the COM platform so it really can do everything on the Windows platform, even if it isn't much fun.

Comment: He rephrased his comment totally before you read my comment and asked about the differences between VB and VB.net

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "my programs are too hard to work with"?
Writing classes does not necessarily make your tool easier to work with...
I also don't really see a problem with using the same code over and over, as long as you respect the general rules of good practise (performant, dynamic, transparent, etc...).

What is there to know about classes?
Classes enable the possibility of creating standard *encapsulated* objects, containing private properties only accessible via class functions (*get* and *let*).
You can *instantiate* a class module into an object instance and create multiple instances of the same class (using the **New** keyword).
You cannot do this with a standard module; even though you can declare private properties for a standard module (which VBA developers mostly use), there will only exist one "copy" of this variable.

Example comparison:
**Standard Module:** 
"m_Standard_Module"*

```
Option Explicit

Private lNumber_Test As Long

Property Get get_Number_Test() As Long
get_Number_Test = lNumber_Test
End Property

Property Let letNumber_Test(param_Number_Test As Long)
lNumber_Test = param_Number_Test
End Property
```

Called from:

```
Sub test_Standard_Module()

Dim iNumber                     As Integer

'--> This will produce an error, cannot be instantiated! 
'Dim mdlStandard                 as m_Standard_Module 


'Property contained by standard module is unique and cannot be copied.
m_Standard_Module.letNumber_Test = 2
iNumber = m_Standard_Module.get_Number_Test
MsgBox iNumber

End Sub
```

**Class Module:**
Class called "c_Class_Module"

```
Option Explicit
Private pNumber_Class As Long

Public Property Get number_Class() As Long  
number_Class = pNumber_Class  
End Property  

Public Property Let number_Class(param_Number_Test As Long)    
pNumber_Class = param_Number_Test
End Property
```

Called from:

```
Sub test_Class()

Dim clsClass_Module1            As c_Class_Module
Dim clsClass_Module2            As c_Class_Module
Dim lNumber1                    As Long
Dim lNumber2                    As Long


'Can instantiate multiple objects!
Set clsClass_Module1 = New c_Class_Module
Set clsClass_Module2 = New c_Class_Module

'property number_Class is copied for each of the class instances  
clsClass_Module1.number_Class = 1
clsClass_Module2.number_Class = 2

iNumber1 = clsClass_Module1.number_Class    
iNumber2 = clsClass_Module2.number_Class    

MsgBox iNumber1 & ", " & iNumber2

Set clsClass_Module1 = Nothing
Set clsClass_Module2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

So basically, class objects would only useful in the case when you want to create multiple instances of a same type of object (having similar properties).
Whenever you make a tool, it is useful to create an object model first, in which you determine the objects needed and their properties you want to create.

Note that VBA does not support inheritance, which means that one class cannot "inherit" properties from another (of which the basic example would be that an Employee class will inherit from a Person class). It has never really bothered me though.

Comment: It does however support interface inheritance

Comment: Full inheritance would actually be the number 1 thing I'd like to see, would make extending standard controls a whole smoother than it is now